# Working with EE Discussion Forum when Structure is installed

Tags: ee2, structure

We've taken over a site at work and they were originally developed in Expression Engine with Structure installed. They recently asked us to install the Discussion Forum module on the site, which we have installed now, but I'm having a hell of a time trying to get it working. My assumption is that real problem here is Structure, but I'm also fairly new to EE, so maybe it's just a lack of knowledge?

I've got the forum working on a new template page using:

```
{exp:forum}
```

I created a page in Structure and assigned it to the template, so when you navigate to the page the forum shows up properly; however, when you try and do anything within the forum, like trying to view a forum or thread, it sends you back to the main site to a blank landing page for the forum page.

The only thing I can think of is that structure is seeing that the "viewforum" or any other page beyond the forum landing page doesn't actually exist.

I ended up installed Freebie hoping that would help solve some of my problems - the forum stopped redirecting back to the main site, but it won't actually work now because it relies on EE's core `uri->segment` and freebie stops that from being processed (at least from my understanding)

I've also tried adding a new channel for the forum and creating the page in Structure using that channel, it still does the same thing when you try to click into a forum.

I really hope someone knows a fix for this, I'm  literally pulling my hair out trying to figure this system out and the documentation on this stuff is very minimal.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 1):

This probably needs ot be run completely outside of Structure and more like traditional EE for the forum to avoid all of the routing/url issues.

Comment: Does that require me to turn off structure completely? Or is there a method to do it where the forum doesn't use structure?

Comment: Just create a forum template group and Structure EE will pick that up

Comment: I just had the same issue myself. I followed Steven's advice and setup a template group and template to handle just the Forum code, and this seems to be working fine alongside Structure.